# Which of these "minimal" semisimple Lie algebras aren't simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, exceptional-isomorphisms

The semisimple Lie algebras, indexed by their Dynkin diagrams, are classified as direct sums of the algebras

$$ \mathfrak{sl}_{n+1} \quad \mathfrak{so}_{2n+1} \quad \mathfrak{sp}_{2n} \quad \mathfrak{so}_{2n+2} \quad E_6 \quad E_7 \quad E_8 \quad F_4 \quad G_2$$

for $n>0$, where $n$ is the rank of the Lie algebra. Are these not all simple? Why not just call these *the* simple Lie algebras?

Comment: Is $\mathfrak{so}_{4}$ simple?

Comment: In additions there are some redundancies in this list, namely $so_5\simeq sp_4$ (type $B_2=C_2$, $so_6\simeq sl_5$ (type $A_3=D_3$).

Comment: @YCor Thank you! (you should add those to the CW answer). Yeah those make sense from the Dynkin diagrams. What's got me weirded out now though is that $\mathfrak{so}_4 \cong \mathfrak{so}_3 \oplus \mathfrak{so}_3$ *doesn't* make sense from the diagrams. In terms of the diagrams, it's not true that $D_2 = A_2$, but instead $D_2 = B_1 \sqcup B_1$.

Comment: @MikePierce Why does it not make sense? $D_2=B_1 + B_1$ is correct. $D_2=A_2$ would correspond to the false isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}_4 \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_3$.

Comment: @pregunton $D_2$ has a two nodes and an edge, but two copies of $B_1$ will be two nodes with no edges. Unless you've have something else in mind writing $B_1+B_1$?

Comment: @MikePierce But $D_2$ does not have an edge.

Comment: @pregunton It's just those two disconnected fork nodes? (spin nodes?)

Comment: @MikePierce Yes, see e.g. the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Finite_Dynkin_diagrams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the odd one out here is $\mathfrak{so}_4$.

$$\mathfrak{so}_4 \cong \mathfrak{so}_3 \oplus \mathfrak{so}_3\,.$$